# Variadic Function That Calls Constructor With Given Arguments

Tags: c++, function, templates, constructor, variadic

Need to create variadic `template<T>` function with different arg types that will call constructor of `T` with given arguments, sort of like when creating a thread but reverse (when creating a thread, its constructor calls function at given funct pointer).

So in pseudo code it should look something like this

```
template<typename T>
T* CreateNew( ARGS ) {
    return new T( ARGS );    //Constructor Gets Same Arguments That Were 
}                            //Passed To The Function
```

Want this to behave like when creating threads, when they call functions with their arguments that are **of different types** (which I am unsure how to achive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to write this function is

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* CreateNew(Args&&... args) {
    return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Without the forwarding reference `Args&&` and without `std::forward`, the original value categories of the passed arguments will not be propagated to `T`'s constructor, causing potential performance and semantic problems.

Answer (score 3):

Its not entirely clear to me but I think you want to look up variadic templates, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* CreateNew(Args... args) {
    return new T(args...);
}
```

Adding Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
    A(int a){
        std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
    }
    A(std::string a){
        std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
    }
    A(int a,std::string b){
        std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T* create(Args... args){
    return new T(args...);
}

int main(){
    A b(1);
    A c("a");
    A d(1,"a");
    A* bp = create<A>(1);
    A* cp = create<A>("a");
    A* dp = create<A>(1,"a");
    // This code leaks
    return 0;   
}
```

Note that because the changes are kept as minimal as possible, we still return a `T*` here as the original code. Most of the time, this is not a good idea since ownership is passed via raw pointers. Therefore, as suggested by the comments, you might want to use a `std::unique_ptr`, which would make your `CreateNew` function basically equivalent to `std::make_unique`.

Comment: For further reading: [Parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: And using `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw owning pointer would be even better (and allow to avoid current memory leaks).

Comment: @Jarod42 your're totally right, thanks for pointing it out. Since I want to keep the changes to OT's code minimal, I just added a comment in the example and a paragraph about using `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`.

Comment: This implementation is broken as it does not perfectly forward `args...`.